# Java: How to spit the line in between two pattern in Java

Tags: java

I am facing some problem with getting the text matching with the two patterns,Please help me out,Here is my question and my requirement :

Line : `selenium.TypeKeys("name=email", "raj@ymail.com");`
My requirement is to Get the name=email from the above line,

Thanks

Comment: Question is not very clear. you want to parse the text or you want to check in the text contains "name=email"

Comment: Nope,Actually i will have mulitple lines in my file,So i want to retrieve the Text which appears in between ("  and ", and want to output it to the some external file.

Comment: Have you tried to use regular expressions ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the value between `"` and `,`.

```
line.substring(line.indexOf("(\""), line.indexOf(","));
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, But my requirement is value in between ("  and ,

Comment: Ok, Modified the code. I just wanted to tell you an apporach.

Comment: iam trying with Pattern but not able to create pattern with using RegExpression